# Why do console.log() polyfills not use Function.apply()?

Tags: javascript, debugging, polyfills

I've been looking at some of the popular `console.log()` wrappers/polyfills:

- [Paul Irish's](http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/)
- [Ben Alman's](http://benalman.com/code/projects/javascript-debug/docs/files/ba-debug-js.html)
- [Craig Patik's](https://github.com/patik/console.log-wrapper)

I notice that all of them accept multiple `arguments`, but they all do something like this:

```
console.log(arguments);
```

Which results in output like this (in Chrome):

[image: <code>console.log(['foo', 'bar', $('body')])</code>]

Whereas, at least in a modern browser like Chrome or Firefox, `console.log()` also accepts multiple arguments, so that this would produce (IMHO) superior output:

```
console.log.apply(console, arguments)
```

Which results in output like this (in Chrome):

[image: <code>console.log.apply(console, ['foo', 'bar', $('body')])</code>]

Is there any particular reason why I should avoid using `console.log.apply()` with multiple arguments? Or this this just a matter of taste or saving bytes?

Comment: @PaulIrish Any thoughts on console.log vs console.log.apply?

Comment: This is probably not the main reason, but the console.log property in IE does not have the Function prototype. I.e., it doesn't have the `apply` function.

Comment: Well hey, that's probably a very good reason.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally suggest that you only use `.apply()` when you have to: `.apply()` is the only way to pass an array as the arguments of a function. If you don't *need* to pass an array, then just use `console.log()`. It is less verbose and it is a direct invocation.

Comment: Well, that's what *I* think, but people who know JS better than I aren't doing this, and so I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `apply` takes an **array** of arguments!

So calling `console.log(args)` have to be `console.log.apply(console, [args])`, not `console.log.apply(console, args)` to behave equal - in your example each item in array becomes his very own argument in apply.

On the other hand you may also call `console.log("foo", "bar", $("body"))`