# Ajax not work on IE10

Tags: ajax, post

I have a demo use jquery ajax post. It can run on Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE10. This is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/44T5D/. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks for you help.

The code:

```
$(function() {

    $('.document').on('click', '.ajax', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // ajax request
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            type: 'post',
            url: '/echo/html/',
            data: {
                html: '<p>This is echoed the response in HTML format</p>',
                delay: 1
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            beforeSend: function() {
                console.log('Fired prior to the request');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Fired when the request is successfull');
                $('.document').append(data);
                alert(data);
            },
            complete: function() {
                console.log('Fired when the request is complete');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Do you have any add-ons, extensions, or other things affecting IE10?

Comment: I see your jsfiddle uses jQuery 1.7.2. Have you tested with 1.9.1?

Comment: I don't know what exactly add-ons or extensions you talking about. But I just installed IE10 yesterday, and only IE10, dont have any add-ons, extensions. Can you tell me more about this error.

Comment: I ask because this other issue was solved by uninstalling some add-on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101729/jquery-ajax-call-works-in-all-browser-except-ie-10

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue because I am allergic to Windows. Just grasping at straws here.

Comment: I've tried with Jquery 1.9.1. It still not  working. :((

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer will error on the various `console` functions unless the developer tools are open. As you have a `beforeSend` handler, more than likely that's where it's stopping execution.

To see if this is indeed the issue, press F12 to open up the developer tools and refresh the page, and see if it works.

As a workaround if you want to keep the `console` functions, look into a console polyfill (some are listed here): [Why do console.log() polyfills not use Function.apply()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584218/why-do-console-log-polyfills-not-use-function-apply)

Comment: I've fixed my code, delete all console functions, use jquery 1.9.1. It work normaly on chrome and FF, but in IE10 it just show alert dialog with blank text when I click the link.

Comment: You have a mis-placed comma on line 19 that's probably confusing IE. As a tip, use the JSHint button in jsfiddle, it will point out errors like this one.

Comment: Hi, I have fixed my code: http://jsfiddle.net/qYXa3/1/ and when I use JSHint, it said:"Good work! Your JavaScript code is perfectly valid.". But still nothing change.