# IE10 - JQuery ajax html not loading data

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-10

I have done some research already by looking at the following post ([Ajax not work on IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607173/ajax-not-work-on-ie10)) and few other websites, but unfortunately it did not fixed my problem and that's why I need your help ;)

Below you can see my JQuery ajax script, My problem is that I can get to ajax and return value to errorDivStyle, but I am not able to load $("#mainView").html(data); data is returned from PHP script and its HTML.

Please note it works perfectly fine in Chrome, FF and IE 9 but NOT IE10. Is there something I am doing wrong ??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var category = $("#category").val();
        $("#category").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data)
                    {
                        $("#mainView").html(data);
                        $("#errorDivStyle").html("<font color='#000000'>" + category + " category have been loaded</font>").show();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `dataType: 'html'` as an [AJAX option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Comment: BTW `<font>` tag is deprecated.

Comment: Did you try hitting F12 in IE to open the developer console and see what the error is in the 'Console' tab? Perhaps your using an old version of jQuery that doesn't support IE10.

Comment: Make sure that you're not using `console.log()` anywhere as it sometimes throws errors if you haven't got developer tools open.

Comment: First of all my JQuery script listed above is correct and works fine. The problem I have noticed is with IE10 and this part "data: $(this).serialize()" For some reason IE10 adds white space on the beginning and the end of the variable which is passed to PHP file B-(. e.g. "KEBABS" is 6 string long, but my PHP script was getting _POST 8 string long " KEBABS ". Can you believe that. Now I need to get something to recognize browsers and remove the white spaces if its IE10

Comment: @pi4r0n Can you clear the space like so `$.ajax({... data: $.trim($(this).serialize()), ... });`? Just trim off the white space after you serialize.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing blatantly wrong with your code.

If you are using a newer version of Jquery then I would suggest changing:

```
$("#category").change(function(){
```

into

```
$("#category").on('change', function(){
```

and certainly after

```
cache: false,
```

add

```
dataType: 'html',
```

Also I highly recommend using console.log()

```
if(data)
{
    //check if expected data is correct
    console.log(data);
    //make sure you can target #mainview properly
    //should output the amount of #mainviews on your screen
    console.log($("#mainView").length);

    $("#mainView").html(data);
    $("#errorDivStyle").html("<font color='#000000'>" + category + " category have been loaded</font>").show();
}
```

EDIT:

```
    $("#category").on('change', function(){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data)
                {
                    $("#mainView").html(data);
                    $("#errorDivStyle").html("<font color='#000000'>" + category + " category have been loaded</font>").show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Why were you returning FALSE anyways? I just realized that this is probably a text field change that you are listening for. So the e.preventDefault() isn't necessary either...

Also if you just want to pass a single value to your test.php then you can try this:

```
    $("#category").on('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php?q="+$(this).val(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                if(data)
                {
                    $("#mainView").html(data);
                    $("#errorDivStyle").html("<font color='#000000'>" + category + " category have been loaded</font>").show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

EDIT: recursively TRIM an array

```
/**
* Returns a recursively TRIMMED variable
*
* @access   public
* @param    mixed
* @return   mixed
*/
if ( ! function_exists('trim_r'))
{
    function trim_r($var)
    {
        //In here you can add more code to handle objects properly but I did not because I am not using them with this function
        //if (is_array($var) || is_object($var)){some code}
        if (is_array($var))
        {
            return array_map('trim_r', $var);
        }
        else
        {
            return trim($var);
        }
    }
}


// Usage examples
$_POST = trim_r($_POST);
$_GET = trim_r($_GET);
$_REQUEST = trim_r($_REQUEST);
$custom_array = trim_r($custom_array);
```

Comment: MonkeyZeus I have tried you way by changing to "$("#category").on('change', function(){" and notice that I get an error in consol "SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visited. " unfortunately I can not see any logs in console (Strange). What I have discovered was that if I run in Browser Mode: IE10 Compat View the change works fine but in another once it does not

Comment: I wonder if the "return false;" is screwing things up for IE. I will edit with a possible solution.

Comment: I haven't experimented with console.log() in IE10 but I could not live without it in Chrome. Open Chrome and hit F12 and go to the console tab, now refresh your page.

Comment: MonkeyZeus Chrome & FF consoles works perfectly fine for me as well and I can see your logging in it ;) Its the IE10 that f... all up :( Let me try your latest fix ;)

Comment: On second thought, are you trying to pass in all of the form data upon changing the text field?? If so then you should be serializing the entire form like this "data: $(this).parents('form').serialize(),"

Comment: Right I have tried the one with e.preventDefault() and removed return false; at the end and this fails as the change does not return any values at all :(.

Comment: I have IE10 installed as well and I am using extremely similar code as you are. You're IE isn't set to a high security level or something is it? Go to Internet Options->Security Tab and scroll through those and see if anything is blatantly blocked these types of requests. Also you are not testing this in IE in a server environment are you?

Comment: Aaaa finally got the debug in IE10 up and running. Looks like my problem is that the data returned from function is blank for some reason. Investigating why is that :)

Comment: Yo ;) When I run my web in  Browser Mode: IE10 Compatibility View my JQuery Script work perfectly fine (data includes html and is displayed) but when I run it in Browser Mode: Internet Explorer 10 it does not (data is blank) Any idea ??

Comment: You have forced me to use the IE console window, I may never heal from this experience lol. Since you are getting blank data for some reason I would head over to the Network tab and click "Start Capturing" then refresh your page and see if your AJAX script throws any server errors. You can also try browsing directly to that script by going like http://www.example.com/test.php and see what kind of errors your server is throwing in IE10. Do you have some sort of USER_AGENT issues going on?

Comment: I found the issue and you not gonna believe what IE10 is doing :) when I get home I will explain ;) PS JQuery script is OK :)

Comment: Right sorry for delay. First of all my JQuery script listed above is correct and works fine. The problem I have noticed is with IE10 and this part "data: $(this).serialize()" For some reason IE10 adds white space on the beginning and the end of the variable which is passed to PHP file B-(. e.g. "KEBABS" is 6 string long, but my PHP script was getting _POST 8 string long " KEBABS ". Can you believe that. Now I need to get something to recognize browsers and remove the white spaces if its IE10

Comment: Ha! Wow that's nuts. I must have never run into this problem because I recursively TRIM whitespace from all of my $_POSTs and $_GETs using PHP before I ever get a chance to handle them in my scripts. Let me know if you're interested in getting that PHP code.

Comment: Yes please MonkeyZeus if you got something that handles that it would be good ;)