# $.getJSON not working in IE10,

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer

I am trying to make a post request something like this. Following line calls a controller action

```
$.getJSON(GetPath('/Products/Search'), param, function (data) {
  // do some thing with data
}
```

`GetPath` gives me a valid URL

```
   function GetPath( url ) {

           var protocol = "http://";

           if ('@ApplicationInstance.Application["IsHTTPS"]' == "TRUE")

               protocol = "https://";

           if ('@HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath' == "/")

               return protocol + window.location.host + url;

           else

       return protocolwindow.location.host+'@HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath' + url;    

       }
```

This is perfectly working fine in chrome as well as safari.

But in IE10 getting an error  message in console

> script1014: invalid character

Is this something to do with Jquery version?

Comment: please add your json response that you are getting back from the server

Comment: use "$.ajax" dataType:"json" ?

Comment: What does `GetPath` return?

Comment: returns a valid path like localhost if i am running the app locally or else the server name if th eapp hosted on server. I edited my question  have a glance

Comment: Read the fourth comment from the bottom of my post on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594510/ie10-jquery-ajax-html-not-loading-data/17594970#17594970 maybe you are having the same issue?

Comment: use $.ajax({}) , that should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Apperantly IE seems to have problems with accessing files directly (without http server).
If you change the request to

```
$.getJSON(GetPath('http://localhost/Products/Search'), param, function (data) {
  // do some thing with data
}
```

(assuming that you're running this in localhost environment)
then this error should dissappear and your code should work.

cfr. [SCRIPT1014: Invalid character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261256/script1014-invalid-character) ; [Getting SCRIPT1014: Invalid character in IE from local js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834261/getting-script1014-invalid-character-in-ie-from-local-js-file)

also clearing the browser cache sometimes seems to help

Comment: 'GetPath' method returns a valid URL, depending on whether the app running locally or on server something like this function GetPath(url) {
               var protocol = "http://";
               if ('@ApplicationInstance.Application["IsHTTPS"]' == "TRUE")
                   protocol = "https://";

               if ('@HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath' == "/")
                   return protocol + window.location.host + url;
               else
                   return protocol + window.location.host + '@HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath' + url;

           }

Comment: Ah OK. Would probably be a good idea to add this in the question :D

Answer (score 0):

```
return protocolwindow.location.host+'@HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath' + url;
```

change

```
return protocol + window.location.host + '@HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath' + url;
```

and getJSON success callback use jQuery.parseJSON

```
$.getJSON(GetPath('/Products/Search'), param, function (data) {
    var search_results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(search_results);
}
```

Comment: This did not help even after modifying still getting error in console js, line 1 character 15735
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character